# What is the difference between Do and Map?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactive

What is the difference between `do` operator and `map` operator?
**It seems the same. I'm learning RxSwift.**

**Please check the marble diagram of do and map.**

do : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html

map : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to what SPatel mentioned,

do: will not modify the emitted elements but rather just pass them through and has no effect on the actual subscription.

whereas

map: transforms  each value of a sequence before emitting on the actual subscription

check this for reference: 
[https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-and-master-️-the-basics-of-rxswift-in-10-minutes-818ea6e0a05b](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-and-master-%EF%B8%8F-the-basics-of-rxswift-in-10-minutes-818ea6e0a05b)

Comment: In other words, `do` is purely for performing **side effects** with the emitted value as it doesn't change it.

Comment: Try avoiding using 'do' as much as possible, as it kind of goes against the functional 'no side effects' philosophy. There are instances where it can be useful, but those are rare.

Answer (score 1):

`map` -> is use to convert one stream into another stream.

`do` -> is use to perform some action or task on every stream event

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/682-rxswift-transforming-operators